# How can I get DATATIME in dd.mm.yyyy format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to name an excel file with date .So I need to name convert in to this format dd.mm.yyyy

Any body can help me ..I tried many ways in C#

```
 Protrac.CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dt, Server.MapPath("~/Profile/" + dunsno +     DateTime.Today.ToShortTimeString()  + ".xlsx"));
```

Comment: I would just google "how to format a date in c#".

Comment: [`DateTime.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Take a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

In your code it would be like:

```
Protrac.CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dt, 
                                   Server.MapPath("~/Profile/" + dunsno 
                                  + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy",
                                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)  
                                  + ".xlsx"));
```

Consider using format `yyyyMMdd` for File name since I have found this useful in sorting files based on names.

For more see: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") should do.

Here is the link to how they work and what other formats you can have. :

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Answer (score 0):

try with `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'.'MM'.'yyyy")`

Comment: The single quotes are not necessary

Comment: @ThomasLevesque yes, in case of `InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

```
Protrac.CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dt, Server.MapPath(string.format("~/Profile/{0}{1}.xlsx", dunsno, DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "~/Profile/{0}{1:dd.MM.yyyy}.xlsx", dunsno, DateTime.Today);
Protrac.CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dt, Server.MapPath(fileName));
```